# CSS on top of Kinetic Layer

Tags: jquery, css, kineticjs

I have a Kinetic layer with rect/paths and in the process of implementing a live search feature in the top navigation area, when the results div appears the div has an opaqueness to it.

My Kinetic layer has an opacity of 0.4 so I am guessing the CSS is inheriting from the Kinetic layer?

```
var mapLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 0.4
});
```

And the results div is:

```
#results {
    display: block;
    width:250px;
    z-index:999;
    height:80px;
    background-color: #CCDDDD;
    opacity:1;
}
```

The layer rect/paths have mouseover events so I would also like these to be ignored when the search results appear:

```
rect3.on('mouseover', function () {
    //alert("Mouseover");
    this.setFill('#FFDD00');
    this.setOpacity(1);
    //this.moveTo(topLayer);
    mapLayer.draw();
});
```

I have put together a JSFiddle which shows what is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/matt_65/kT32e/

Comment: I see no opacity in your results div (http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/kT32e/3/) - the only thing that is opaque is the canvas with the kenetic stuff on the right?

Comment: Thanks, what I mean is that the DIV is a solid colour but the kinetic layer/objects are appearing within the DIV.  How can I make the DIV appear on top of the kinetic stuff?

Comment: just add `position:relative;` to `#results` - z-index only applies to positioned elements: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/kT32e/4/

Comment: Beautiful, I normally do that for my DIV's, love that it was something so simple.  If you want to put it as an answer I will then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your `#results` div and it should work - `z-index` will only apply to positioned elements:

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/kT32e/4/)